# Is there a method to use Javascript or jQuery to launch Chrome Find? (Same as ctrl + f)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on an extension and rather than build my own search functionality, I'd rather just use Chrome's for searching a page for text. Is there a way to create a button that says "Search" and when clicked will be the same as a CTRL + F keypress by the user?

I apologize if this is a redundant question. I didn't succeed in finding it here already.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.find

```
Testing test

<form onsubmit="window.find(this.q.value,false,true,true,true,false,true); return false">
<input id="q" type="text" value="test" />
<input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>


Testing test
```

Note: I could only make this do a find BEFORE (or after if set to search backwards) the input field for some reason

Update: Had a [quick google](http://www.google.com/search?q=trigger%20find%20dialog%20chrome) and this showed up: https://github.com/philc/vimium/wiki/Chromium-bugs-we%27re-tracking

Comment: I just tried it and had the same experience. Also only seems to return the first match. (Or, highlight it, as the case may be.) Any idea how to use the built-in little chrome widget?

Comment: I could make it cycle. And no I do not know how to call the widget from script

Comment: I see. It cycles with each successive submission... thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps API not implemented yet? (couldn't find much more info)

http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/814d8558bb56218c/7aa645e9aeca5cfb?lnk=gst&q=ctrl+f#7aa645e9aeca5cfb